# What intellji plugin can help to improve java coding?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is an example, the original code (if i remember) is

```
public static List<String> transform(List<String> listOfString) { 

    return listOfString.stream()
                       .map(str -> toUpperCase(str))
                       .collect(toList());
}
```

If you look at the line of map, it can be improved

```
public static List<String> transform(List<String> listOfString) { 
    return listOfString.stream()
                       .map(String::toCamelCase)
                       .collect(toList());
}
```

My question is, any plugin can reminder me about this ?

Comment: IntelliJ's default behavior will flag this, you just need to pay attention to the alerts it gives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use "Replace lambda with method reference" quick-fix (available at Alt+Enter)
[image]

provided by "*Lambda can be replaced with method reference*" inspection (Java | Java language level migration aids | Java 8 | Lambda can be replaced with method reference).

Answer (score 1):

Sure i suggest you sonarlint!

Take a look at it:

[SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/)